# TypeScript Record of custom type as Key

Tags: typescript

I have a question regarding TypeScript records being used with a custom Type as a key.
So Basically I have a custom type (a limited set of strings) which I want to use as keys for my record. And I want to initialize this record as empty.

```
type MyCustomType = 'property1' | 'property2';


class MyClass {
    public myRecord: Record<MyCustomType, number> = {};
}
```

but doing so throws:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<MyCustomType, number>'

is there any way, maybe `Partial<MyCustomType>` as the record Keys that allows me to achieve this?

I want to avoid creating the record as `Record<string, number>`

Comment: You can write `Partial<Record<MyCustomType, number>>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N72PRw); does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to accomplish this

```
type MyCustomType = 'property1' | 'property2'
const myVar = <Record<MyCustomType, number>>{}
// or: const myVar = {} as Record<MyCustomType, number>
myVar.property2 = 1 // will work
myVar.property3 = 2 // won't work
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this made the trick :) 

Could you enter on more detail on why my approach is not working but with type assertions it is? Which is the difference between using `:` to define type then initialize and initalize with type asertion?